# Apache Kafka : commitSync after pause

Tags: apache-kafka, commit, offset, kafka-consumer-api

In our code, we plan to manually commit the offset. Our processing of data is long run and hence we follow the pattern suggested before

1. Read the records
2. Process the records in its own thread
3. pause the consumer
4. continue polling paused consumer so that it is alive
5. When the records are processed, commit the offsets
6. When commit done, then resume the consumer

The code somewhat looks like this:

```
   while (true) { 
          ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(kafkaConfig.getTopicPolling());
                if (!records.isEmpty()) {
                    task = pool.submit(new ProcessorTask(processor, createRecordsList(records)));
                }
                if (shouldPause(task)) {
                    consumer.pause(listener.getPartitions());
                }
                if (isDoneProcessing(task)) {
                   consumer.commitSync();
                   consumer.resume(listener.getPartitions());
                }
    }
```

If you notice, we commit using commitSync() (without any parameters). 
Since the consumer is paused, in the next iteration we would get no records. But commitSync() would happen later. In that case which offset's would it try to commit? I have read the definitive guide and googled but cannot find any information about it.

I think we should explicitly save the offsets. But I am not sure if the current code would be an issue.

Any information would be helpful.

Thanks, 
Prateek

Comment: hi @Prateek Negi, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you call `consumer.commitSync()` with no parameters it should commit the latest offset that your consumer has received. Since you can receive many messages in a single `poll()` you might want to have finer control over the commit and explicitly commit a specific offset such as the latest message that your consumer has successfully processed. This can be done by calling `commitSync(Map<TopicPartition,OffsetAndMetadata> offsets)`

You can see the syntax for the two ways to call commitSync here in the Consumer Javadoc http://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitSync()

Comment: The documentation says "Commit offsets returned on the last poll() for all the subscribed list of topics and partitions".

When paused, the last poll has not pulled any records. Will it still commit the last offset that the consumer had received in earlier poll ?

Comment: @chirunner Can you confirm that commitSync() commits latest offset that the consumer received or that was received by last poll(). In case of paused consumer, this might mean different things.

Comment: I can't confirm that because I've never personally run it that way. I would call commitSync after a pause but before another poll. Even better would be to call commitSync and provide an explicit list if offsets to commit since you may not have finished processing all the messages from the last poll. It should however be easy for you to test what gets committed in the scenario you are asking about. My educated guess is that it would be the highest offset return in any of the previous calls to poll()